# How to uninstall bun

Tags: javascript, uninstallation, bun

I installed bun on windows (ubuntu) with this command:

```
https://bun.sh/install | bash
```

Now I want to remove bun and reinstall it (not upgrade)

Comment: Uninstall instructions here: https://bun.sh/docs/installation#uninstall

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you look at the [source for the installation script](https://bun.sh/install) (and I mean, *surely* you did that already, before blindly executing code from the internet. Right? Right..?), you can find that

- `bun_install="${BUN_INSTALL:-$HOME/.bun}"` – the default install directory is `$HOME/.bun`
- the script additionally adds that to your shell's configuration, i.e.

  - `.config/fish/config.fish` if you're using Fish
  - `.zshrc` if you're using zsh
  - or you've manually added it to your path following instructions if you're using another shell.

Thus, uninstallation means:

- removing `~/.bun`
- removing those shell configuration customizations

Comment: I could read the shell script, but then I googled it, and there was an SO post.